# error google speed Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP

Tags: google-pagespeed

Today began to speed up the loading of the site and PageSpeed ​​Insights displays
constantly mistake
"Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. При записи трассировки для вашей страницы произошла ошибка. Перезапустите Lighthouse. (NO_FCP)"
Here is my site https://gospodaretsva.com

What could be the problem, searching the forum to solve my problem could not

Comment: now it produces this error: "Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you have some firewall on your computer that is interfering with the request.

'Shields Up' on Brave browser tends to be the culprit a lot of the time if you are using that.

I just ran it and it worked fine for your site, you got 51 on mobile, 93 on desktop.

Comment: thanks I will try on another pc, on this I tried from different browsers. Then I will unsubscribe

Comment: The problem was apparently this, on the other pc everything is fine

Comment: Glad you managed to test, unusual for a problem to persist across browsers, perhaps you have an anti virus program that is intercepting requests, maybe try whitelisting Google or temporarily switching your AntiVirus off.